# Getting to SVN from TeamCity using Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, svn, authentication, teamcity

I am trying to setup TeamCity on my Windows XP machine. It is failing to get the code from subversion because of an authentication error. I have put my windows domain\user username and password into the TeamCity configuration - but it looks like it's trying basic authentication. What do I need to change?

Here is the TeamCity SVN log (the actual server/port has been replaced with server:port):

[2009-05-28 17:37:43,375]  DEBUG -                 javasvn.output - NETWORK: SENT

OPTIONS /svn/External HTTP/1.1

Host: remote.server:port

User-Agent: SVN/1.5.5 SVNKit/1.2.2 (http://svnkit.com/) r5405

Keep-Alive:

Connection: TE, Keep-Alive

TE: trailers

Authorization: Basic bWVybG90L21hcmt3OiVyZnZjZGUz

Content-Length: 0

Accept-Encoding: gzip

Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"

DAV: http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/svn/depth

DAV: http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/svn/log-revprops

DAV: http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/svn/mergeinfo

[2009-05-28 17:37:43,453]  DEBUG -                 javasvn.output - NETWORK: READ

HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required

Date: Thu, 28 May 2009 05:38:56 GMT

Server: Apache

WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Subversion Repositories"

Content-Length: 401

Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

[2009-05-28 17:37:43,453]  DEBUG -                 javasvn.output - NETWORK: svn: Authentication required for 'https://server:port Subversion Repositories'

Comment: Umm... actually this may be a bug in the version I'm using - i'm just downloading the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded latest version (4.5.1 (build 8975)) and it worked out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](http://blog.alanta.nl/2008/09/teamcity-and-subversion-with-ntlm.html).

Comment: Not sure if this has been fixed since this then, but installing the latests "just worked". Thanks for your time!